# Using a subset of Pandas dataframe with Scipy Kmeans?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a data frame that I import using `df = pd.read_csv('my.csv',sep=',')`. In that CSV file, the first row is the column name, and the first column is the observation name.

I know how to select a subset of the Panda dataframe, using:

`df.iloc[:,1::]`

which gives me only the numeric values. But when I try and use this with `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans` using this command,

`kmeans(df.iloc[:,1::],3)`

I get the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you not just select the first column and pass this? something like `kmeans(df.[df.columns[0]],3)`

Comment: I want to run kmeans using all the columns except the first column (because the first column is full of strings).

Comment: well `kmeans(df.[df.columns[1:]],3)` does that

Comment: Ahh. I get `kmeans(df.[df.columns[1:]],3)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Sorry typo, should be: `kmeans(df[df.columns[1:]],3)`

Comment: Exact same error, 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'. Is it because even when selecting the subset of numeric-only elements, it's still a 'dtype' object and not a 'float64' one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example to use KMeans.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# try to simulate your data
# =====================================================
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, centers=3)

columns = ['feature' + str(x) for x in np.arange(1, 11, 1)]
d = {key: values for key, values in zip(columns, X.T)}
d['label'] = y
data = pd.DataFrame(d)

Out[72]: 
     feature1  feature10  feature2  ...    feature8  feature9  label
0      1.2324    -2.6588   -7.2679  ...      5.4166    8.9043      2
1      0.3569    -1.6880   -5.7671  ...     -2.2465   -1.7048      0
2      1.0177    -1.7145   -5.8591  ...     -0.5755   -0.6969      0
3      1.5735    -0.0597   -4.9009  ...      0.3235   -0.2400      0
4     -0.1042    -1.6703   -4.0541  ...      0.4456   -1.0406      0
..        ...        ...       ...  ...         ...       ...    ...
995   -0.0983    -1.4569   -3.5179  ...     -0.3164   -0.6685      0
996    1.3151    -3.3253   -7.0984  ...      3.7563    8.4052      2
997   -0.9177     0.7446   -4.8527  ...     -2.3793   -0.4038      0
998    2.0385    -3.9001   -7.7472  ...      5.2290    9.2281      2
999    3.9357    -7.2564    5.7881  ...      1.2288   -2.2305      1

[1000 rows x 11 columns]

# fit your data with KMeans
# =====================================================

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit_predict(data.ix[:, :-1].values)

Out[70]: array([1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of make_blobs? Perhaps I don't understand Kmeans that well, but in Matlab you can simply input a matrix where rows are observations and columns are the different variables you would like to use in the cluster analysis, and the number of clusters you would like, and it spits out an index array assigning each observation to one of the three clusters.

Comment: It just generates some artificial clustering data. Here, I try to simulate a sample with 1000 obs, where each obs has 10 features. There are 3 cluster centers in total.